# Как считать из файла одну пару строк?

Tags: java

у меня есть пустые String A и String B и есть 2 строки в файле:
МАМА
ПАПА
Нужно прочитать эти строки, чтобы первая строка соответствовала String A
а вторая String B

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи `BufferedReader` в `try-with-resources`:

```java
String mama;
String papa;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))) {
    mama = br.readLine();
    papa = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println(mama + " and " + papa);
```

---

При помощи `Scanner`:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))
mama = input.nextLine();
papa = input.nextLine();
```

---

Можно прочитать массив/список строк с использованием "новой" модели ввода-вывода NIO `Files.lines`:

```java
String[] lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt")) // Stream<String>
    .limit(2) // взять 2 первые строки
    .toArray(String[]::new);

mama = lines.length > 0 ? lines[0] : null;
papa = lines.length > 1 ? lines[1] : null;
```